# Сетевое подключение не видно из программы

Tags: c++, macos, carbon

Основная программа запускает внешний процесс, который создаёт сетевое подключение. Основная программа до перезапуска не видит это сетевое подключение.

Вопрос - как увидеть сетевое подключение, созданное во внешнем процессе?

Сетевые подключения перечисляю так:

```
CFArrayRef connArray = SCNetworkServiceCopyAll(PrefsAccess::instance().prefs());

if (!connArray) return 0;

for (CFIndex i = 0, sz = CFArrayGetCount(connArray); i < sz; ++i)
{
....
....
}
```

Comment: А не пробовали пересоздавать `SCPreferencesRef`?

Comment: Пробовал, но сейчас перепроверил - была ошибка. Пересоздание SCPreferencesRef помогло. Огромное спасибо!